# Android 25 Java : Using methods that require Context in a different Class - Require assistance

Tags: java, android, android-context

I created a simple little directory listing method in the default MainActivity.class

I was able to get it to function the way I wanted it to, however, when I moved the method to a different class and called it in MainActivity, I wound up getting a lot of Context Errors all over the place. After searching the web I am stumped and require assistance.

The code where it errors out is for the Context for FileArray:

```
(public class Utilities extends Activity)
arrayAdapter = new FileArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_explorer,dir);
```

Method Name:

```
public void listDirectories(ListView listView, File directory)
```

It errors out on the `getApplicationContext,` this method worked just fine in MainActivity.

I have not implemented `Fragments` to `MainActivity` yet, wanted to get the working functionality first then spread out for OOP; then call by Fragment.

Hope someone can help, any further info I am happy to share.

Comment: Which error occurred ?

Comment: Fatal Exception: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: use it inside method instead of at class level

Comment: you need to pass Context as parameter to the method

Comment: Ya I have thought that might be the issue. It does allow if I label as final for the OnTouch listener. However getApplicationContext or getBaseContext are throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the timely response: ρяσѕρєя K &  Nilabja.
Ya I guess it just needed another person to suggest feeding Context as a param. I did that once but it did not work so I passed it off, attempted once again from  Nilabja suggestion. Yip that was the solution.

```
utilities.ListDirectory(mainList, root, getApplicationContext());

public void listDIR(ListView listView, File directory, Context setContext)
```